# HTML title no multiline

Tags: html, title

I'm facing a problem in HTML, I have something like this:

```
<td title="line1
    line2
    line3
    line4">
```

But I don't want my web web browser displays it like this. I want a one line pop up like this

"line1 line2 line3 line4"

In google there is only subject with people want to display a multi line pop up... Is there an HTML option? Is it possible to do that?

BR

Comment: Why not use `<td title="line1 line2 line3 line4">`?

Comment: If I do the line is longer than 80 chars.

Comment: Have you tried using `&nbsp;` instead of spaces?

Comment: If you have to worry about this, you are probably using too long `title` attribute values and should reconsider their use. They have horribly poor accessibility, especially when they are long; use other ways to present information to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have any control on how the popup is rendered when using an attribute title. It is up to the browser. If you want in all on a single line you would have to change the way the title attribute is generated to strip all the newlines/linefeeds. Its the only way to have it all one one line.

Comment: Ok I will probably make the sentence in my controller and send the sentence to my view. I don't like so much this way but it seems I don't have the choice. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<td title="line1 line2 line3 line4">
```

Comment: If I do the line is longer than 80 chars.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways of doing this

`white-space:nowrap` will make sure it doesn't break to a second line

```
<p class="nowrap">line1 line2 line3 line4</p>

.nowrap{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

`display:inline` will put `ul li`s on a single row

```
<div class="inline">
    <ul>
        <li>line1</li>
        <li>line2</li> 
        <li>line3</li>    
        <li>line4</li>               
    </ul>
</div>

.inline ul li{
    display:inline;
}
```

`display:inline-block` can be used to put divs on a single row

```
<div class="inline-block">line1</div>
<div class="inline-block">line2</div>
<div class="inline-block">line3</div>
<div class="inline-block">line4</div>

.inline-block{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and you could also use `<span>Text</span>` within an element

```
<p><span>line1</span><span>line2</span><span>line3</span><span>line4</span></p>
```

hope this helps in giving you a few ideas and be able to see which one will work best for you.